# Tests pass in Eclipse but fails in Gradle. Related to assertThat

Tags: java, junit, gradle

I have a test that perfectly works in Eclipse but fails in Gradle. I am not sure what is wrong. I am using Java 8 in Eclipse.

prompt:

```
E:\Files\Source\Workspace-Eclipse2\project\src\test\java\com\project\core\domain\TeamUnitTest.java:31: error: no sui
table method found for assertThat(List<User>,Matcher<Collection<Object>>)
                assertThat(team.getUsers(), empty());
                ^
    method Assert.<T#1>assertThat(T#1,Matcher<? super T#1>) is not applicable
      (actual argument Matcher<Collection<Object>> cannot be converted to Matcher<? super List<User>> by method invocati
on conversion)
    method Assert.<T#2>assertThat(String,T#2,Matcher<? super T#2>) is not applicable
      (cannot instantiate from arguments because actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Object declared in method <T#1>assertThat(T#1,Matcher<? super T#1>)
    T#2 extends Object declared in method <T#2>assertThat(String,T#2,Matcher<? super T#2>)
E:\Files\Source\Workspace-Eclipse2\project\src\test\java\com\project\core\domain\TeamUnitTest.java:51: error: no sui
table method found for assertThat(List<User>,Matcher<Collection<Object>>)
                assertThat(team.getUsers(), empty());
                ^
    method Assert.<T#1>assertThat(T#1,Matcher<? super T#1>) is not applicable
      (actual argument Matcher<Collection<Object>> cannot be converted to Matcher<? super List<User>> by method invocati
on conversion)
    method Assert.<T#2>assertThat(String,T#2,Matcher<? super T#2>) is not applicable
      (cannot instantiate from arguments because actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Object declared in method <T#1>assertThat(T#1,Matcher<? super T#1>)
    T#2 extends Object declared in method <T#2>assertThat(String,T#2,Matcher<? super T#2>)
2 errors
:compileTestJava FAILED
```

test code:

```
assertThat(team.getUsers(), empty());
```

Comment: Chances are that the Gradle build is compiling with an earlier Java version which doesn't like this code. Check which JVM version is displayed by `gradle -v`.

Comment: Add explicit dependency to Hamcrest 1.3 and use JUnit 4.11.

Answer (score 3):

It would seem that your gradle build isn't pulling in the same junit or hamcrest that Eclipse is, but instead an older one. You should set explicit dependencies.

If you put this class into `src/test/java/SOTest.java`

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class SOTest {
  @Test
  public void doTest() throws Exception {
     // Regular JUnit assert
     assertEquals(true, true);

     // Hamcrest assertThat
     List<Object> teamUsers = Collections.emptyList();
     assertThat(teamUsers, empty());
  }
}
```

Then create a `build.gradle` file with this in:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
sourceCompatibility = 1.6

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
    testCompile group: 'org.hamcrest', name: 'hamcrest-core', version: '1.3'
    testCompile group: 'org.hamcrest', name: 'hamcrest-library', version: '1.3'
}
```

And build, the test of `assertThat(Collection,empty())` will run and pass.

The difference here is we're explicitly depending on a new version of junit, and on the hamcrest 1.3 version with those matches in it.